# derivative of a numerical expression

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I have a function $$g(y) = \int{f(y, t)dt}$$ and I am currently able to evaluate the integral numerically (doesn't seem like it is possible to find an analytical solution...), which I have also plotted for various values of $g(y)$. All good so far. However, I am also interested in the quantity $$\frac{dg(y)}{dy}$$ Is there a way to obtain this derivative?

Comment: Under appropriate conditions, we might expect $g'(y)=\int{f_y(y,t)dt}$. Typically, though, the integral is a *definite* integral and the computation is done with some type of software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In common cases it is possible to swap the integral and the derivative so that:
$$\dfrac{\partial g(y)}{\partial y} = \int \dfrac{\partial f(y, t)}{\partial y}dt$$

For this equality to be true you need an inversion result, a sufficient condition is that the partial derivative of $f$ is continuous w.r.t. both $y$ and $t$ and bounded uniformly w.r.t. $y$ on the domain of integration. The last condition means that there exist a function $h$ on the domain of $t$ such that for all $x, t$: $\|\dfrac{\partial f(y,t)}{\partial y}\| \leq h(t)$.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can use finite differences as below
$$g(y_0+h)\approx g(y_0)+g'(y_0)\cdot h+O(h^2)$$
$$g(y_0-h)\approx g(y_0)-g'(y_0)\cdot h+O(h^2)$$
By substracting second from first
$$g(y_0+h)-g(y_0-h)\approx 2g'(y_0)\cdot h$$
$$\Rightarrow g'(y_0)\approx\frac{g(y_0+h)-g(y_0-h)}{2h}$$
Or in discrete notation
$$\Rightarrow g'(y_i)\approx\frac{g(y_{i+1})-g(y_{i-1})}{2h}$$